# My wordpress website has a critical error

Tags: wordpress, loading

The error message I get:
[image: wordpress image]

Hey, so I pasted some simple html into the header section of my wordpress website (Straight into the code and uploaded it through filezilla).

As soon as that happened my website wouldn't load and instead gave me the critical error message.

I went back a few steps and reversed any changes I made before the error... but I still have the same issue.

I entered the debug function into the config.php file, and the picture attached is the error message I got.

Any help on how to rectify this situation would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to download and installing stable version

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `wp-config.php` sample on your file manager or file browser, copy the codes inside of it create a new `wp-config.php` paste the codes then reconfigure the connection strings like `db_name`, `db_user`, `db_password` check for the table prefix as well usually it's `wp_` then click save the error shows for `wp-settings.php` means unable to read that file from the `wp-config.php` It means `wp-settings.php` maybe corrupted or need a debug. The instructions I provided is the easiest one instead of debugging the code for `wp-settings.php` on line 528. The error mostly happens in a hosting server.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try downloading a new version of wordpress and replacing your current (broken) one: https://wordpress.org/download/